# How to reuse list entry anchor in YAML?

Tags: yaml, anchor, circleci

I am trying to write a CircleCI config that will allow me to reuse not the whole entries (like e.g. full `docker` section definition) but singular entries on a list (like used docker images)

Let's say I need to reuse `alpine`'s image in a couple of places

```
docker:
  - image: alpine:3.10
    environment:
      LATENCY: 0
```

I would like to be able to define different stacks:

```
docker:
  - image: postgres:12
  - image: spotify/kafka:latest
  - image: redis:2.8.23
```

and put there the above defined `alpine` image in this list.

I've tried with e.g.

```
docker:
  - &default image: alpine:3.10
    environment:
      LATENCY: 0

build-step:
  docker:
    - *default
    - image: postgres:12
```

but that doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this:

```
docker:
  - &default image: alpine:3.10
    environment:
      LATENCY: 0
```

then the anchor `default` will point to the string `alpine`.

If you want to create an anchor for a mapping (or a sequence), then the anchor must be on its own line:

```
docker:
  - &default
    image: alpine:3.10
    environment:
      LATENCY: 0
```

Then you can use it as you already did:

```
build-step:
  docker:
    - *default
    - image: postgres:12
```

Comment: How do I use it then?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was obvious. Just use it as you did already. I edited my answer

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can achieve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095057/how-to-reuse-anchored-entry-under-already-unwrapped-anchor ?